# How to add to an object keys and values of a Map as properties?

Tags: javascript

I have this object

```
const obj = {a: 1}
```

and this map

```
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('b', 2);
map1.set('c', 3);
```

How can I add keys and values from map1 as **obj** params/values?

```
obj = {a: 1, b:2, c:3}
```

**EDIT**: just edited the object 'obj'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a good ol' `forEach()` to add values to your object.

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1
};
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('b', 2);
map1.set('c', 3);

map1.forEach((value, key) => {
  obj[key] = value;
});

console.log(obj);
```

Or use `Object.fromEntries()` in combination with the spread syntax.

```js
let obj = {
  a: 1
};
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('b', 2);
map1.set('c', 3);

obj = {
  ...obj,
  ...Object.fromEntries(map1),
};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: `Object.assign` can also be used like `Object.assign(obj, Object.fromEntries(map1))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('a', 1);
map1.set('b', 2);

const obj = Object.fromEntries(map1)
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(map1);
```

you can also check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Answer (score 0):

you could use Object.fromEntries method to do such a thing

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(map);
```